# How to get all values from a column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Example:

SQL DATABASE

```
    Firstname   Age
    Paul        14
    Andrea      15
    John        18
    Mary        20
```

I wanted to get the values from column "Age", and add it all. (I'm a newbie to SQL commands), So my output would be 67.  Is this even possible?

Comment: if you're way too newbie and set the Age type into varchar, then things get complicated.

Answer (score 5):

```
select sum(age)
from dbo.YourTableName
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQL Sum function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) to sum up your age column like:

```
Select Sum(Age) as TotalAge from yourtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Age) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) function like

```
SELECT SUM(Age) as Total
FROM yourtable
```

> Returns the sum of all the values, or only the DISTINCT values, in the
>   expression. SUM can be used with numeric columns only. Null values are
>   ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Use following sql

```
SELECT SUM(Age) as AgeTotal from dbo.YourTableName
```